# HTML based HTTP POST request failing using Ajax

Tags: html, json, ajax

I am writing a sample HTML code, in which calling HTTP post using Ajax function.

I need to call 2 HTTP POST and 1 GET requests as below (one after another based on correct response.)

1. POST:

URL:
http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_testjson_consumer

Body:
{"name": "my_cons3_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}

Header -> Content-Type : application/vnd.kafka.v2+json

When it gets proper response, call the next POST request below.

2. POST:

URL:
http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_testjson_consumer/instances/my_cons3_instance/subscription

Body:
{"topics":["testkafka"]}

Header -> Content-Type : application/vnd.kafka.v2+json

When it gets proper response, call the next GET request below.

3. GET

URL:
http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_testjson_consumer/instances/my_cons2_instance/records

Here is the sample HTTP POST code below for the first request: But this is not doing POST request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<title>My jQuery JSON Web Page</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

JSONTest = function() {

    var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_testjson_consumer/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "name": "my_cons3_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            switch (result) {
                case true:
                        console.log("processResponse");
                    processResponse(result);
                    break;
                default:
                    resultDiv.html(result);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
};

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My jQuery JSON Web Page</h1>

<div id="resultDivContainer"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="JSONTest()">JSON</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I need advise for 2 queries.

1. I don't know why is the above code not working as expected and getting response back. I should get response as: `"{ "instance_id": "my_cons2_instance", "base_uri": "localhost:8082/consumers/my_testjson_consumer/instances/…; }"`
2. How can i call all the mentioned above 2 POST request and 1 GET one after another based on each one's response?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Call the second Post request in the success function of the first Post call and the Get call in the success function of the second post call.

Here is the structure you would want to put

```
$.ajax({method:'post',url:...,success: function(){
 $.ajax({method:'post',url:,..., success: function(){
    $.ajax({method:'get':,..., success: function(){
        //do something here
     }), error: function(){}
  }), error: function(){}
 }), error: function(){}
```

});

Comment: Ok thanks. I am not sure why is first http post method is failing there. I should get response as for the first request: "{
    "instance_id": "my_cons2_instance",
    "base_uri": "http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_testjson_consumer/instances/my_cons2_instance"
}"

Comment: Do you want to try changing the 'type' key to 'method' in the ajax calls. The original ajax definition has them as 'method'. I believe the call doesnt identify 'type' and hence defaults to 'get'.

Comment: No, method is not working. Type is the correct one I believe. If I use method, it takes default as GET method.